# compare date split across columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying tables from Microsoft SQL 2008 which have date split across 3 columns: day, month and year. Unfortunately, I do not have control over this because data is coming in to the database daily from a 3rd party source in that format.

I need to add *between* to a *where* clause so user can pull records within a range.  Would be easy enough if date was in a single column but finding it nearly impossible when its split across three columns.

To display the date, I am doing a

```
CAST(
    CAST(year as varchar(4)) + '-' + 
    CAST(month as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
    CAST(day as varchar(2))
as date) AS "date"`
```

in a *select*. I tried to put it as a parameter for *datediff* function or just the regular *between* but get no results.

Comment: Can you add an indexed computed column to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to change the table, you can use a subquery to construct the date before the filtration is applied:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST(year as varchar(4)) + '-' + 
                    CAST(month as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
                    CAST(day as varchar(2)) AS date) AS [date]
                    ...
          FROM ...) x
 WHERE x.[date] BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

If using SQL Server 2005+, you can use a Common Table Expression (CTE) instead -- but there's no performance difference between using a CTE vs the subquery approach:

```
WITH example AS (
   SELECT CAST(CAST(year as varchar(4)) + '-' + 
               CAST(month as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
               CAST(day as varchar(2)) AS date) AS [date]
               ...
     FROM ...) 
SELECT x.*
  FROM example x
 WHERE x.[date] BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

### Caveats:

Because the dates are being constructed on the fly, this will never perform as well as if the values were stored as DATE or DATETIME -- an index on the year, month or day columns can not be utilized.  Options to consider would be an [indexed view (AKA materialized view)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx), or [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot about sub-queries...  May try to do computed column when time not an issue, because performance will be a problem with millions of rows this thing has. Will have to see if the daily income of data resets the schema every time or not otherwise no way to store computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider adding a [Computed Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) if searching for dates/ranges is a common requirement